# queries on bigquery taking more time

Tags: google-bigquery

I have uploaded file of 80,00,000 observations of 10+1(also tried with 20+1 and 100+1) variables, all variables are binary(0,1) except weight(float) and executed some simple queries like:

```
SELECT sum(col1),sum(wt*col1),sum(col2),sum(wt*col2),sum(col3),sum(wt*col3),sum(col4),sum(wt*col4),sum(col5),sum(wt*col5),sum(col6),sum(wt*col6)
,sum(col7),sum(wt*col7),sum(col8),sum(wt*col8),sum(col9),sum(wt*col9),sum(col10),sum(wt*col10)
FROM [bigquery_dummy_dataset.bin_006b];
```

this query is taking `5.6 secs approx` while executing it for `100 columns is taking 21 secs approx`. I feel it slower than other existing database technologies(In sql server by using indices we have achieved higher performance) .However, I want to process more data (upto 2000 variables).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to speed up elapsed time?

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Big Query is a highly scalable database, before being a "super fast" database. It's designed to process HUGE amount of data distributing the processing among several different machines using a technique named Dremel. Because it's designed to use several machines and parallel processing, you should expect to have super-scalability with a good performance.

**2)** BigQuery is an asset when you want to analyze *billions of rows.*

For example: analyzing all the wikipedia revisions in 5-10 seconds isn't bad, is it? But even a much smaller table would take about the same time, even if has 10k rows.

**3)** Under this size, you'll be better off using more traditional data storage solutions such as Cloud SQL or the App Engine Datastore. If you want to keep SQL capability, Cloud SQL is the best guess.

Sybase IQ is often installed in a single database and it doesn't use Dremel. That said, it's going to be faster than Big Query in many scenarios...as designed.

**4)** Certainly the performance differ from a dedicated environment. You get your dedicated environment for 20K$ a month.